# Parent-child height problem

Tags: css

I have a parent div that has `position: relative` and his child has `position: absolute`. Such positions is a must. The problem is the parent does not stretch to the height of the child. The question is how to make it stretch to the height of the child?

The mark-up is similar to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .parent {
                position: relative;
                border: solid 1px red;
            }

            .child {
                position: absolute;
                border: solid 1px red;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="parent">
            <div class="child">Hello World!</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `overflow:hidden` to your parent.

**Edit:** My mistake, this will only work if the children are floating. This cannot be achieved if the child is position absolutely. When you absolutely position an element, you're taking it out of the document flow. As far as positioning is concerned, that element is no longer a "child", even though semantically it still is.

Comment: How would that help? I need to make the parent stretch to the height of the child. I do not want to hide its content...

Comment: Adding `overflow:hidden` works because it tells the DOM that the element hasLayout=true. A lot of DOM elements completely ignore height settings unless they are explicitly instructed to do so.

Comment: @Jarrett It doesn't work. Using overflow:hidden will not change the dimensions of the parent element. It will just hide all content that goes beyond the borders of that element.

Comment: My apologies, you guys are right; It doesn't work. I mistaked the question for using floating children, not absolutely positioned children. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

give a `height:100%` to both the child and the parent.

Comment: This guess does not help too.

Comment: This will only work if both elements are block (not inline) elements.

Comment: Divs are block elements but it does not settle the problem down. Please see http://jsfiddle.net/vhgFn/1/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think there's a way to do it, without using Javascript.

edit: Perhaps if you show why they need to be position:relative and position:absolute, we can come up with a way to remove that restriction so that what you want is possible.